# Error in deserialising JSON using C# "A object does not contain definition for B"

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON and as soon as I try to access anything else but "main" it get an error

> Error CS1061  'RootObject' does not contain a definition for 'clouds' and no accessible
> extension method 'clouds' accepting a first argument of type 'RootObject' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is the JSON:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Auckland,NZ&APPID=45c3e583468bf450fc17026d6734507e&units=metric

```
{"cod":"200","message":0,"cnt":40,"list":[{"dt":1577178000,"main":
{"temp":13.68,"feels_like":12.74,"temp_min":13.68,"temp_max":14.66,"pressure"
:1010,"sea_level":1010,"grnd_level":1001,"humidity":87,"temp_kf":-
0.98},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear 
sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":2.04,"deg":227},"sys":
{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2019-12-24 09:00:00"},
```

[image]

This is my code. I made classes according to the JSON structure but it doesn't like it. Anyone a clue how to do get *clouds*, *weather* and *wind* to work too?

[image]

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<myWeather> list { get; set; }  
    }
    public class myWeather
    {
        public Main  main { get; set; }
        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
        public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
        public string dt_txt { get; set; }
    }
    public class Main 
    {
        public float temp { get; set; }
        public float humidity { get; set; }
    }
    public class Clouds
    {
        public float all { get; set; }
    }
    public class Weather
    {
      //  public int id { get; set; }
     //   public string main { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
     //   public string icon { get; set; }
    }
    public class Wind
    {
        public float speed { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
              
           string[] temps = new string[10];
           string[] humidities = new string[10];
           string[] clouds = new string[10];
           string[] sky = new string[20];
           string[] wind = new string[10];

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("ACCESSING jsonWeather ...");
                string jsonWeather = client.DownloadString("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Auckland,NZ&APPID=45c3e583468bf450fc17026d6734507e&units=metric");
                
                var myweather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonWeather);
                               
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var json in myweather.list.Take(3))
                {
                    i++;
                    temps[i] = json.main.temp.ToString();
                    humidities[i] = json.main.humidity.ToString();
                    clouds[i] = json.clouds.all.ToString();
                    wind[i] = json.wind.speed.ToString();
                }
                
                int k = 0;
                foreach (var jsonc in myweather.list.Take(3))
                {
                    k++;
                    sky[k] = jsonc.weather.description.ToString();
                }


                Console.WriteLine(sky[1] + " " + temps[1] + " " + humidities[1] + " " + clouds[1] + " " + temps[2] + " " + humidities[2] + " " + clouds[2] + " " + temps[3] + " " + humidities[3] + " " + clouds[3]);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're accessing main in a loop over the myWeather elements in `myweather.list.Take(3)`, while trying to access clouds right out of RootObject. Maybe `myweather` is not the best name for the deserialized RootObject, maybe you should just call it `rootobject` for clarity.

Comment: It works fine for main only - when I delete the classes for Clouds, Weather and Wind. But I don't know why. Weirdly, i can leave in 

public Clouds clouds { get; set; }

but adding

public Weather weather { get; set; }

gives me an error when the program runs.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access `myweather.clouds`, but there is no such property in myweather. Property `clouds` is hidden under `list`, so it should be at least `myweather.list.First().clouds`.

Comment: That fixed that problem but then the compiler tells me "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ConsoleApp2.Weather' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."

Comment: take a look at weather, according to the json - it is an object that contains array of objects, but in your c# code it is just a class with one property.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be something wrong in the way I have defined the classes. but I really can't tell what.. *scratch

Comment: change myWeather and Weather classes to these:

public class myWeather
{
        public Main  main { get; set; }
        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
        public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
        public string dt_txt { get; set; }
}
public class Weather
{
 public int id { get; set; }
 public string main { get; set; }
 public string description { get; set; }
 public string icon{ get; set; }
}

Comment: Thanks Roman, the weird thing is that it works with main and clouds but as soon as I define **public Weather weather { get; set; }** the program gives me a JSON error when running.

Comment: That is because it should an array of Weather, not a single object. Use code from previous comment, it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot! That worked and I see now the difference int he JSON structure. Holy moly... When using **sky[k] = jsonc.weather.description.ToString();** It now complains that *'List<Weather>' does not contain a definition for 'description' and no accessible extension method 'description' accepting a first argument of type 'List<Weather>' could be found*

Comment: I guess it is from this line clouds[k] = jsonc.weather.description.ToString();
You are again trying to access property that does not exist. Weather is a List now, so you should access element of this list and only then description. i.e. jsonc.weather.First().description.ToString();

Comment: Thanks, that line of code did the rest. I am measurably grateful for your help and time. I literally have no idea why adding *First()* helps but the rest of the code (which is also a list) does work without First(). Why do i need First() for weather and not for temp? See updated code :)

Comment: .First() is not a right solution here, it is just an example how it could work. First() or FirstOrDefault() is used for collections when you want to get first element from this collection. In your case you have a collection of objects and in order to access a property of one of this object, you need to get this object first, that is what First does, get one element from collection.

Comment: Thanks. it works, tho. What I am wondering is why it works without First() when using **json.main.temp** but i have to set **json.weather.First().description**. It should be the same structure and principle how to access the data?

Comment: main is single object, weather is collection, does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks Roman. Yes, it does. But **list** is a collection too, or not? Whats the technical difference such that I don't need to apply **First()** for **list**?

Comment: list is collection, yes, but main is not a list, it is a single class object, that is why you don't need to apply First().